# Explode a .txt files into multidimenional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, file

currently, I'm working on reading a folder where are living all my .txt files then read all files data and store it to a database. This is my code for taking all data from the file and parse it to the array:

```
/**
     *
     * @param array $paths [files/8754D394_20200219131722_oplog.txt]
     * @param string $file_name [8754D394_20200219131722]
     * @param string $file_name [8754D394_20200219131722]
     * @param array $explodes [[1 => 8754D394, 2 => 20200219131722]]
    */
    public function index()
    {
      $paths = glob('files/*.txt');
      foreach ($paths as $key =>$path) {
        // files name and storing it to array
        $file_name = basename($path, '_oplog.txt');
        $explodes = explode( '_', $file_name );
        $data_file = array();
        $data_file[$key] = $explodes;

        // Date
        $full_date = substr($data_file[$key][1], 0, -6);
        $years = substr($full_date, 0, -4) . '-';
        $months = substr($full_date, 4, -2) . '-';
        $days = substr($full_date, 6);
        $full_date = $years . $months . $days;

        // storing data to database
        $fileDatabase = new File();
        $fileDatabase->name = $file_name;
        $fileDatabase->vei_id = $data_file[$key][0];
        $fileDatabase->file_date = $full_date;
        // $fileDatabase->save();


          $content = file_get_contents($path);
          $content = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $content);
          $content = explode(';', $content);
          unset($content[count($content) - 1]);

          $data_content = array();
          $data_content[$key] = $content;
          foreach ($data_content[$key] as $row) {
            if($row == '\n') {
                $data_content[] = $row;
            }
          }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data_content);
        echo "</pre>";
      }
    }
```

The problem is that I need, that my array look like that:

file1.txt

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19/02/2020 12:17:05
            [1] => OBD
            [2] => SetSpeedLimit
            [3] => FR
            [4] => HW3
            [5] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19/02/2020 12:17:05
            [1] => OBD
            [2] => SetSpeedLimit
            [3] => FR
            [4] => HW3
            [5] => 
        )
)
```

file2.txt

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19/02/2020 12:17:05
            [1] => OBD
            [2] => SetSpeedLimit
            [3] => FR
            [4] => HW3
            [5] => 
        )
)
```

file3.txt

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19/02/2020 12:17:05
            [1] => OBD
            [2] => SetSpeedLimit
            [3] => FR
            [4] => HW3
            [5] => 
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19/02/2020 12:17:05
            [1] => OBD
            [2] => SetSpeedLimit
            [3] => FR
            [4] => HW3
            [5] => 
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19/02/2020 12:17:05
            [1] => OBD
            [2] => SetSpeedLimit
            [3] => FR
            [4] => HW3
            [5] => 
        )

)
```

and so on...

But I getting like that:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25/01/2020 08:57:53
            [1] => OBD
            [2] => FLASHWrite
            [3] => MR
            [4] => A7
            [5] => 
            [6] => 25/01/2020 09:08:58
            [7] => OBD
            [8] => FLASHWrite
            [9] => MR
            [10] => A7
            [11] => 
            [12] => 25/01/2020 09:16:39
            [13] => OBD
            [14] => FLASHWrite
            [15] => MR
            [16] => A7
            [17] => 
            [18] => 25/01/2020 10:48:45
            [19] => OBD
            [20] => FLASHWrite
            [21] => MR
            [22] => A7
            [23] => 
        )

)
```

I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Where does `$path` come from, its not a object property and its not passed as a param to the `index` method?

Comment: It comes from my public folder named "files"

Comment: It does now, after you completely changed the code you show us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the use of `file_get_contents` to read a csv file, which is not appropriate at all. Also, if you remove the line breaks before exploding your string, there's little chance of getting a multidimensional array.
Instead, read your file line by line using `fgetcsv` with `;` as delimiter.

```
public function index()
{
    foreach (glob('files/*.txt') as $index => $path) {
        $filename = basename($path, '_oplog.txt');
        list($id, $date) = explode('_', $filename);
        $content = array();

        $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd+', $date)->format('Y-m-d');

        // storing data to database
        $fileDB = new File();
        $fileDB->name = $filename;
        $fileDB->vei_id = $id;
        $fileDB->file_date = $date;
        // $fileDB->save();

        // your files are csv files, read them line by line with fgetcsv
        if ( false !== $handle = fopen($path, 'rb') ) {
            while ( false !== $fields = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ';') ) {
                array_pop($fields);
                $content[] = $fields;
            }
            fclose($handle);

            echo '<pre>', print_r($content, true), '</pre>';
        } // else you can throw an exception if you can't read the file
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!